# The script duplicates the work in loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have main page:

**index.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
<head>
...
    $(".get_ajax").on("click", function(){

        $(".for_ajax").show();
        $(".for_ajax_content").html('<div class="LK_Loader">'
                                        + '<img src="./images/loader.gif" title="wait answer.." alt="wait answer..." width="25">'
                                        + '</div>');
        $.post('./func.php?cmd=get_ajax', function(data){
            $(".WindowInGame .WindowInGameText").html(data);            
        });

    });
    $(".for_ajax_exit").on("click", function(){

        $(".for_ajax_content").html('');
        $(".for_ajax").hide();
        ajax_script_end = true;
    });
...
</head>
<body>
    ....
    <button type="button" class="get_ajax">get_ajax</button>
    <div class="for_ajax">
        <div class="for_ajax_exit">X</div>
        <div class="for_ajax_content"></div>
    </div>
    ....
</body>
</html>
```

in **func.php** i get content file **test.php**:

```
<button class="test" type="button">test</button>
<script>
    var can_start = true;
    $("body").on("click", ".test",function(){
        console.log('can_start = ' + can_start);

        if(!can_start){
            alert("wait - script working");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            can_start = false;
        }

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "./func.php?Cmd=StartScript",
          data: {val:'start'},
          success: function(msg){
            var answer = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
            if(answer.error == '0'){
               setTimeout(function(){
                    alert('script work end');
                    can_start = true;
                }, 20000);                            
            }
            else{
                alert(answer.answer);
            }
          }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Logik work:

1. I click on button `<button type="button" class="get_ajax">get_ajax</button>` on main page.
2. With ajax i load content page `test.php` on main page in window `for_ajax_content`
3. In content(which was load on `for_ajax_content` i click on button `test` and send ajax.
4. after get answer i set `can_start` in `true` and show `alert('script work end');`

I see problem for me:

1. i open page `main.php` and load content `test.php`
2. i close loaded content - i click on `for_ajax_exit`, it clear `for_ajax_content` and hide `for_ajax`
3. i make this operation 2 or more steps
4. after step 3 if i open console and load page `test.php` in console i see:

   ```
   can_start = true; //corret value
   can_start = false; //not corret - why do I get this value immediately after load script?
   ```

AND if i click on button `test`, than i get `alert("wait - script working");`. after click `ok` in alert, script send on `func.php?Cmd=StartScript`

I think that loaded script duplicated(i'm right or not ? ), but how destroy loaded script(which script in timeout) when i exit from loaded content(which click on `for_ajax_exit`) ?

P.S.: script in loaded content should be in this content. If I wrote something is not clear, i will gladly explain.